# genymotion или родной эмулятор от андроид студио?

Tags: android, эмулятор

Genymotion все хвалят. Установил , дал ему характеристик по-лучше, но он максимум 30 фпс в простенькой игрушке выдает, когда мой телефон 150-200. А родной эмулятор 100 фпс.

Я так понимаю дело в том, что у меня Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager и мне не нужен этот Genymotion? Genymotion это как решение для тех кто на AMD или без аппаратной виртуализации, я прав?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В последнее время "родной" эмулятор SDK очень сильно продвинулся, как в плане производительности, так и функциональности. Например, на относительно слабой машине с Core i3 6100 эмуляция не вызывает какого-то дискомфорта в плане скорости работы или начального старта.

Если процессор поддерживает виртуализацию VT-x (современные Intel), то лучше использовать эмулятор SDK Android. Тут и любые аппаратные конфигурации (можно создать вручную любое устройство) со всеми возможными API Android, все возможные Android устройства (как часы, телевизор и тд). Большие возможности эмуляции датчиков устройства (температуры, освещенности, давления, магнитного поля и тд с ручной настройкой), эмуляция всей переферии устройства: батарея, внешние звонки\смс, интернет, сканер отпечатков пальцев и тд. Ни одно альтернативное решение не обладает такими возможностями.

Единственная причина использовать сторонний эмулятор на сегодняшний день - ОС Windows и процессор не имеет аппаратной виртуализации VT-x (процессоры AMD и старые Intel), тогда работа эмулятора из- за программной эмуляции неудовлетворительно медленна.

На ОС семейства Linux эмулятор SDK поддерживает гораздо большее число аппаратных виртуализаций процессоров, в частности процессоры AMD (технология AMD-V (svm)), из-за использования виртуализатора QEMU и виртуальной машины KVM ([как настроить](http://craigthomas.ca/blog/2014/06/06/android-emulator-vm-acceleration-on-amd/))

[Офф.документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) эмулятора

Comment: Ну я так и предположил, когда увидел, что Genymotion у меня очень медленный. Решил его попробовать потому , что родной эмулятор иногда подвисает намертво после закрытия приложения, но это еще зависит от того насколько качественное приложение

Answer (score 2):

Эмуляция - дело тонкое. И не всегда предсказуемое.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424721/why-genymotion-emulator-is-a-lot-faster-than-android-emulator

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator