# Какое железо рекомендуется для Android разработки?

Tags: android, android-studio

Пожалуйста аргументируйте ваш выбор, и еще, не надо копировать требования для Android Studio, я уже их знаю.

Comment: Вопрос должен быть закрыт, так как на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Ну а вопрос всё равно должен быть закрыт, потому что субъективен

Comment: Вот вам [статейка с хабра](https://habr.com/post/433604/) на тему. А так да - вопрос оффтоп и ничего кроме `больше = лучше` сказать не получится.

Comment: Но тут просят переоткрыть вопрос... Давайте попробуем - вдруг чего напишут хорошего? =)

Comment: из-за macOS, считаю, что "маки" - лучшее, что есть для разработчика (не только Android). Купите нормальный мак и будет вам удобство винды и все плюсы линукс в одном флаконе...

Comment: @mit, и кроссплатформа. Но отсутствие виндовых приложений и другой стиль работы. Так что на любителя. Плюс ПК всё равно можно сделать лучше, чем ноут, а также его проапгрейдить в дальнейшем. Так что чисто для Андроида брать лучше ПК. Да, смотреть надо на цену. Я бы брал Мак только из-за Android и iOS. Macbook Pro 2021 M1 Max среди ноутбуков самый быстрый сейчас.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, чего это все накинулись то? Нормальный вопрос.

Вообще основные узкие места (в порядке убывания) это:

1. Скорость эмулятора
2. Скорость сборки
3. Поддержка аппаратного коннекта к девайсу

Итак по порядку:

1) По скорости эмулятора сейчас конечно же лидируют Linux сборки, конечно есть [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) - который хорош, но все таки родной эмулятор как бы лучше. В последнее время разрыв между скоростью работы Windows эмулятора и Linux эмулятор существенно сократился, но Linux эмулятор все равно делает Windows эмулятор.

2) Для скорости сборки важны 3 параметра:

- Наличие большого RAM (ну хотя бы 8 гигов)
- Наличие SSD (от 100 гиг)
- Hyperthreading/многоядерность (ну на i5 тяжеловато будет)

3) Данная проблема возникает, когда необходимо протестировать прогу на реальном девайсе. Под Linux есть проблема коннекта ко многим девайсам. Линуксоиды могут как угодно с пеной у рта доказывать что *там все ок*, но это факт математический... Под Windows проблем существенно меньше. Как правило, у любого более-менее нормального вендора есть драйвера под свои телефоны - установил, воткнул и все работает.

**про Маки** - говорят сейчас все ок, пробовал да все отлично, но я не маковод - не мое это.

**Про видеокарты и проч:** не надо этим заморачиваться. Есть проблемы с 4k мониторами, Android Studio только недавно научился справляться с 4k мониторами, GenyMotion до сих пор не поборол их. И кое-где все равно дурацкий артефакты выскакивают, то шрифт слишком крупный/мелкий, то менюшка вылезет не туда - ну в общем вы поняли.

В общем советую остановиться на ноутбуке с процессором i7 и SSD диском и по максимуму набейте ему RAM - этого точно хватит.

Comment: прекрасный ответ, все по делу)) Даже просидев несколько месяцев за android разработкой все-равно нашел в вашем ответе много чего нового и интересного.

Comment: _Hyperthreading/многоядерность (ну на i5 тяжеловато будет)_ - Честно говоря, не замечаю особой разницы между i5 второго поколения и i7 пятого поколения.

Comment: @Эникейщик, почему не замечаете? Поколение здесь ключевое (вместе с энергопотреблением типа U, M). Например, у меня i5 третьего поколения, а на работе - 10. Разница огромна.

Answer (score 0):

Аккумулируя данные из ответа Barmaley можно составить такой вариант машины:

- AMD FX8320E| AMD Ryzen 4ядерные - 2400G/2500x, с большим количеством ядер - любой райзен.
- 4x4Gb 1866+MHz RAM в случае с FX и DDR4 3000MHz CL14 8/16Gb в случае с райзеном
- 1050ti|1060-3/6|RX 570-4/8|RX580-4/8

Примерно такой конфиг получается. Писал с учётом стоимости железа.
Процессор можно взять и от intel, но сейчас они на порядок дороже, а сильно большей производительности в компиляции/рендеринге ждать не приходится.

Comment: Зато от Intel приходится ждать технологию VT-x для эмуляции виртуальных устройств. На процессорах AMD работа эмулятора это боль, не знаю правда  как там для Ryzen + Hiper-V последнее решение (подключение, по крайней мере, тот еще квест). Всякие GenyMotion это тоже так себе альтернатива и по возможностям [от стандартного эмулятора существенно отстает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612389/177345) и по количеству эмулируемых устройств и по эмулируемым функциям.

Comment: На порядок - это в десять раз. Сейчас скорее наоборот, у Intel будет дешевле, чем у AMD.