# Подойдёт ли такой ноутбук для Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Intel Core i7-2620M 2.70GHz 3.40GHz Turbo Boost Hyperthreading
8Gb DDRIII
240Gb SSD

Comment: такой ноутбук подойдет

Comment: Intel Core i5 4310U,если с таким процессором тоже пойдет?

Comment: любой подойдет. я на самом дешевом работал норм

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для комфортной работы студии подойдет любой компьютер с процессором, поддерживающим технологию VT-x (все более менее современные Intel) - но это нужно только для работы собственного эмулятора (о необходимости данной функции смотрите в дополнении ниже), оперативной памятью не менее 8 гб (чем больше, тем существенно лучше) и ssd-диском (тоже существенное условие комфортной работы).

Мощность процессора не так важна при этом, как быстрый обмен данными (на что напрямую влияет размер оперативной памяти и скорость обмена с диском),  так как происходит создание и обработка большого количества маленьких файлов. Нагрузка на процессор и вычисления при этом не так значительны.

Так же очень влияет на производительность исключение студии (в том числе и Gradle, Git и все другое связанное, как и Java со всеми ее связями) , всех их кэшей  и папки проекта из наблюдения и сканирования антивирусами.

Дополнение: в последних версиях студии появилась возможность использовать Hyper-V в качестве виртуальной машины для эмулятора, что позволяет запустить эмулятор с приемлемой производительностью и на процессорах AMD, поэтому теоретически подойдёт любой более-менее современный процессор. Теоретически, потому что сам я эмулятор на Hyper-V не использовал и о практике его использования утверждать не могу.
Отдельно хочу заметить по поводу необходимости использовать эмулятор вообще, когда можно взять реальное устройство. Да, реальное устройство во всем лучше эмулируемого и позволяет отловить специфические проблемы, но мало кто может позволить себе держать достаточное количество таких устройств. Эмулятор же может предоставить вам любую конфигурацию, оттестировать всевозможные датчики (некоторых из которых может не быть в вашем реальном устройстве), а так же весь спектр устройств, как wear, tv, auto. В чем, кстати, стоковый эмулятор студии [сильно выигрывает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612389/177345) у того же эмулятора Genymotion, возможности которого сильно в этом плане ограничены (малое количество эмулируемых устройств). В общем, если вы беретесь за разработку достаточно серьезно, то эмулятор вам безусловно понадобится, соответственно и процессор компьютера должен быть совместим с технологиями эмуляции (vt-x или hyper-v), пожалуй это единственное существенное требование к процессору компьютера (а не частота, ядра и тп)

P.S: у меня core i3 6 поколения, 32 оперативы и ssd - никаких проблем нет

Comment: А если не запускать эмулятор, то и VT-x не требуется.